# Inserting values : prepared statement or multiple values query?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

In your opinion and from a performance point of view, what is the best solution to insert multiple values in a table ?

**1 - With Prepared statement :**

```
$usersId = Users::getAllId($this->sql);
$prep = $this->sql->prepare('INSERT INTO notification_actualites (idUser,idNews) VALUES(:idU,:idN)');
foreach($usersId as $idU)
{
    $prep->execute(array(
        ':idU' => $idU,
        ':idN' => $idN
    ));
}
```

**2 - Or with a multiple values query :**

```
$usersId = Users::getAllId();
$values='';
foreach($usersId as $id)
{
    $values.='(\''.$id.'\','.$idActu.'),';
}
$values = substr($values,0,strlen($values)-1);
$this->sql->query('INSERT INTO notification_actualites VALUES'.$values);
```

The security aspect is not a problem here , in both case, the code is adapted to prevent sql injection.

A well-argued answer would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the later method. Every database request has to be sent to the database server and receive the results - that takes time, especially if the database server is running on a different machine.

time_to_prepare_query + time_sending_query + time_to_executing_query + time_receiving_results + time_processing_results

When using the second method, I don't have to count the time_sending_query and time_receiving_results *n* times (*n* being the number of rows sent to the db).

On the other hand, you have less control over resolving the possible individual errors that might arise (like duplicate keys (although `ON DUPLICATE KEY` can save you some trouble), bad values etc).

The choice of your method will - as always - depend on your application.